# JIRA JQL Search by Date - How to search Updated Issues on 1 Hour

Tags: filter, jira, jql

These are my Requirements:

I need to get Updated JIRA issues through RSS Every 1 Hour or Minutes.

So how can I filter the issues for my requirements?

What I tried so far:

I have filtered like, **updated > startOfDay(-0d) and updated < now()**

First time it returns the all issues i created or modified to me. But after that it returns all the previous issues along with modified issues.

I need only

> issues which modified between now() and before 1 hour.

How can I create a JQL query like this?

Answer (score 5):

You want the following:

```
updated >= "-1h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a query with where clause `updated BETWEEN LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1) AND LocalDateTime.now()`?

Also you need to pass starting date (in my example LocalDateTime.now() from JodaTime is used) in order to get real start time instead of current time. It may be few seconds later and you will not find several issues updated on the beginning of last hour.